# Response Code 400 on android studio but works fine with POSTMAN

Tags: android, json, android-studio, post, response

I've double checked my url and request size, both are working fine with POSTMAN but give error on Android Studio.

This function parse jsonObject to string

```
private static String encodeParams(JSONObject params) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
public static String sendPost(String r_url , JSONObject postDataParams) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(r_url);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(20000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    String res= encodeParams(postDataParams);
    writer.write(res);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode(); // To Check for 200
    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line="";
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }
        in.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is my object and url:

```
 final JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("Role", "Admin");
            object.put("Email", "Swaiarashad@gmail.com");
            object.put("Password", "dfsdfsc231PW");
            String http = "http://" + constants.ip + "/WcfService/Service1.svc/signin";
            return webService.sendPost(http,object);
```

URL: http://192.168.100.110/WcfService/Service1.svc/signin

Comment: `192.168.100.110` is in a private network, so depending on how you are testing this the device/virtual device might not just be able to access that address.

Comment: I'm testing it on same laptop, my server and client are on same device. i.e. where I ran POSTMAN and it returned results..

Comment: Ah yes, you are getting [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400), so at least the server does receive it, but the client is doing something wrong.